# android svg rendering with linked bitmap

Tags: android, svg, bitmap, android-imageview, android-glide

I want to display an SVG file from a web server in an Android ImageView. For this I use the classes from the [Glide example](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg) on Github.
In my SVG file there is a bitmap linked with the `<image>` tag. The ImageView shows the SVG without the linked bitmap. Is there any way to display everything?
SVG Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="5796177" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="2048px" height="1536px" viewBox="0 0 2048 1536" fill="none">
  <title>pic4.bmp</title>
<image x="0" y="0" width="2048" height="1536" xlink:href="pic4.bmp"/>
<g xml:space="preserve" stroke="#0000FF">
  <polygon class="ROI" fill="none" points="272,0 1887,0 1887,1535 272,1535 " />
</g>
<g xml:space="preserve" stroke="#00FF00">
  <polygon class="result" fill="none" points="770,1300 795,1366 861,1341 837,1276 " stroke-width="4" />
  <text x="770" y="1441" font-family="monospace" font-size="38">6001419050006584,26,100,1</text>
  <text x="770" y="1504" font-family="monospace" font-size="38">Data Matrix, 5.07 PPM</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

The bitmap is in the same folder and in the Windows browser, the SVG is displayed correctly.

Comment: bitmap is not a vector object. Best way is to use converted vector xml without glide

Comment: The files are generated, so I have to convert them automatically.